# PHP - Can't Remove Carriage Return / Space

Tags: php, regex, utf-8, explode, carriage-return

I am reading from a MySQL Database.

The field `upc` reads as:

`811657019822 
843018021328`

I only want the first numbers; there is a space/carriage return and for some reason I cannot explode it out or trim it out. When I convert to XML it displays as:
`<g:gtin>811657019822&#13;843018021328</g:gtin>`

Here is what I have tried in PHP and the result:

[image]

When I do a `var_dump` it shows this:

`string(25) "811657019822
843018021328"`

Notice how they are not all on one line?

It doesn't appear to be a line break as the XML returns a Carriage Return.  Any ideas on what to try to remove everything after the first numbers?

**UPDATE**
As pointed out by @Don't Panic I have erroneously mistaken my slashes the wrong way and should of only been using `\r`.

This is what worked correctly:
`explode("\r", $product['upc']);`

Comment: Could try to first clean by replacing all `\r` `\n` `\r\n` `char(13)` with a single `\n`... then explode on the `\n`.

Comment: It could be *just* `\r` or `\n` instead of `\r\n`. Your `/r/n` attempt is also using the wrong slashes.

Comment: `&#13;` is just `\r`.

Comment: `ord("\r") = 13`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explode with `'/r/n'` won't work for a couple of reasons. For one you'd need to use a double quoted string, with backslashes instead of forward slashes, like `"\r\n"`. But there isn't a `\n`, just an `\r`.

Try using

```
explode("\r", $yourString);
```

Comment: You are correct.  I messed up with wrong slash.  This correctly works for me: `explode("\r", $product['upc']);`